# Prevent IE from page caching

Tags: internet-explorer, cache

I am forced to use IE at work and it caches a notorious amount of pages. I understand that pressing `SHIFT` when hitting refresh forces it to reload the page from the server but I am unable to find a settings option to change the policy to do it on every page visit.

Is it possible to do and how is it done?

Comment: What about safe mode?

Comment: whatever gets it to refresh every time.  how do i do the safe mode?

Comment: even SHIFT-Refresh doesn't work.  i am running my own web server and when i shut it down, cached pages still display even with SHIFT.  gawd, what a P.O.S. !

Comment: I mean you can always Google. Here is one http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/run-internet-explorer-9-without-addons-in-safe-mode/

Comment: Your using the wrong shortcut.  The shortcut to force a refresh is actually `CTRL+F5`

Comment: thanks -- i really want it to be done by default -- is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] I am unable to find a settings option to change the policy [...]

Here it is:

1. Click the *Gear* icon (upper right corner) and choose **Internet Options**.
2. Go to **General → Browsing history → Settings**.
3. Select **Every time I visit the webpage** and click **OK**.